# Установка Java в флешку

Tags: java

Возможно ли установить Java прямо на флешку чтобы написаны на Java запускались прямо с флешки и не требовали утановки Java в ОС на которой запускается? 
Если нет то можно ли найти локальный установщик без скачки Java потоком из установщика?

Comment: папка с jre находится рядом с твоей программой. создаешь bat-файл, который выполняет `../jre/bin/java.exe -jar myProgram `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JRE не требует установки и размножается методом `Copy&Paste`. Многие десктопные Java-программы распространяются как Java-программа со своей JRE в комплекте. Например - Maple.

Другое дело, что под каждую платформу нужна своя версия JRE.

Comment: Спасибо огромное очень выручили.